# Sending Json Object from Server to Client JAVA

Tags: java, json, client-server

Given the following JSON object example:

```
jsonObject.put("Names", jsonArray);

try{

    FileWriter jsonFileWriter = new FileWriter(jsonFilePath);
    jsonFileWriter.write(jsonObject.toJSONString());
    jsonFileWriter.flush();
    jsonFileWriter.close();

    System.out.print(jsonObject);

} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am using JAVA Server and Client that are using sockets, can I use

```
os.println(jsonObject);
```

To send it to the client, or is there another method to send the JSON object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to call the `toJSONString()`:

```
os.println(jsonObject.toJSONString());
```

Otherwise the `toString()` method is called on `jsonObject`.